# WP_Insert_Post change status depending on previous submissions

Tags: wordpress, status

I have created a frontend form that allows logged in users to submit content to my wordpress site. The form allows them to submit to a custom content type. I would like be able to change the status of the submitted post depending on that users previous submissions. So if they already have 1 or more published posts then the submission goes to publish - if they don't then it goes to pending.

I know the argument that I need to change: `'post_status' => 'publish'` - I just don't really have a clue how to start on the logic - let alone what the most efficient way of achieving it will be...?

Answer (score 0):

first, set post_status as a PHP variable that is set by a function, and hard coded returned from within the function.

Then, refactor the function to do a separate WP_Query to find the count of published custom post types with the current userid as author. If >=1, return 'publish' else return 'draft'